# SQL YTD on each Month per Year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
oDate        oValue
----------------------------
2017-01-01   40
2017-02-01   50
2017-03-01   60
2017-04-01   10
```

The data is only one on each month.
Then, I want to have the following result:

```
oDate        oValue         YTD
----------------------------------------
2017-01-01   40             40
2017-02-01   50             90
2017-03-01   60             150
2017-04-01   10             160
```

So, the `YTD` value is the total of `oValue` from previous month and it will ends on december on selected year. When the new `Year` is began, then it will calculate again ignoring the previous year.

Does anyone have the idea for this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the running sum functionality:

```
select odate, ovalue,
       sum(ovalue) over (partition by year(odate) order by odate) as ytd
from t;
```

This is a window function.  The `partition by` restarts the sum each year.  The `order by` does the cumulative sum within the year.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery to find the cumulative total:

```
SELECT
    t1.oDate,
    t1.oValue,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.oValue) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.oDate <= t1.oDate AND YEAR(t1.oDate) = YEAR(t2.oDate)) AS YTD
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY t1.oDate;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: it doesn't ignore the previous year if I add a new date on the different year.

Comment: @Haminteu I added a check so that the cumulative sums happen separately for each year.